# Can the interval $[0,1]$ be made into a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

After some cups of coffee with a friend we come up with a non-trivial question to our knowledge and it reads as follows :

> Is is possible to define the operations of sum and product on $[0,1]$ so that makes it a field ?

As mentioned, this question is most likely beyond of my reach. So, could you give me some lead to solve this problem ?

Comment: It is not closed under standard addition, 1+1 is not inside the set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is there a field with the same cardinal as $[0,1]$? Yes: take $(\Bbb R,+,.)$, for instance. So, take a bijection $b\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ and define on $[0,1]$:

- the additive identity is $b^{-1}(0)$;
- the multiplicative identity is $b^{-1}(1)$;
- $x+y=b^{-1}\bigl(b(x)+b(y)\bigr)$;
- $x.y=b^{-1}\bigl(b(x).b(y)\bigr)$.

And now you have a field $([0,1],+,.)$, which is isomorphic to $(\Bbb R,+,.)$.

Comment: But does not it contradicts the uniqueness of $\Bbb R$ as the only complete ordered field ?

Comment: @Souza It certainly doesn't.

Comment: The new operations on $[0,1]$ do not preserve order, so you don't get an ordered field.

Comment: @Souza $\mathbb{R}$ is the only complete ordered field up to isomorphisms...

Comment: This question and this answer show that mathematics is way more beautiful than its applications. Thank you.

Comment: In any Field the additive identity and the multiplicative identity must be clearly specified. Not only their existence but also their actual construction must be shown. You are also not sure of the characteristic of the Field constructed. So I am not convinced about the Field [0 1]. Some more details may probably convince me.

Comment: @LawrenceMano The additive identity of the field is $b^{-1}(0)$ and the multiplicative identity of the field is $b^{-1}(1)$, where $b: [0, 1] \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is the bijection given above.

Comment: @LawrenceMano I have added the additive identity and the multiplicative identity to my field. And my field has characteristic $0$, since it is isomorphic to $(\Bbb R,+,.)$.

Comment: A well defined function must have its range clearly specified. Additive identity is a nunnary function of selection. So if the range consisting of one element is not specified it's not well defined.

Comment: @LawrenceMano Which function did I mention whose range is not clearly specified? What is a “nunnary function”?

Comment: Any set of cardinality c is a field then. OK OK. I am willing to accept this. But there is no use in such a Field. It will lie a Field on paper. A nunnary function is a selection and as extensions we have unary binary trinary functions.